# Issue with glass transparent render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Im having issue with the back long bottles. When the back bottles are hidden i cant see the green bottle shade

[image]

When the bottle are visible i can see the green bottle through the seeds or the pulses. As the pulses or seed are fully covered till top. Why some top part having issue. Any suggestion or help whats going wrong. Im using **cycles render**.

[image]

I have attach the Bottle model. If download you can see the nodes of the bottle.

In the bottle file you can find the nodes.
[image]

Comment: do these lines also appear in your final render, or just the viewport?

Comment: @haarigertroll no the lines do not appear just the green material peeping inside the pulses bottle

Comment: You simplified blend too much, hard to replicate the issue, but I would say - add Solidify modifier to the object to get some thickness of glass and not a volume filled by glass could help.